# Save the state of input elements in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [Jquery Datatable](http://datatables.net/).In my datatable there are some editable fields but when i do pagination , sorting or change the size of my table , i lost my changes. 
I read somewhere to add submit event handler in a form , but my datatable is not inside a form. Please suggest me the way so that i can preserve my changes even after applying pagination , sorting etc.

PS : I am populating the data through ajax calls

Thanks $ Regards
Tarun Madaan

Comment: I think there's a property in the initialisation object `bStateSave : true` that enables state saving when sorting / moving between pages when data has been manipulated / changed. Maybe this might help you.

Comment: Thanks David for replying but it didn't work :(

Comment: Need to see your code to be able to help.